# Android Landscape to portrait not loading screens when orientation changed

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I have created a layouts for large screens for both portrait and landscape ,and i have a signin.xml in both the layouts, but when i change the screen orientation it doesnt load the  landscape xml instead it changes to landscape mode but the portrait xml  is been loaded .
I have mentioned  onconfig changes in  manifest also,and please let me know how to save data when orientation changed
and please show me some example .

Below is my java code

```
              public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
          super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

               Display display = ((WindowManager)       getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
            int   orientation = display.getOrientation(); 
            boolean oAllow = false;
            switch(orientation) {
            case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
            if(!oAllow ) {
                    setRequestedOrientation    (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

            }
            break;
        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
            if(!oAllow) {
                    setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            }
            break;
    }
      }
```

How can i get my landscape view when i change landscape to portrait to landscape?

please  Any suggestions? Thanks  in Advance

Comment: I think you really needs to read the developer document.  You should only define the layout file to different resource folder.

Comment: i have added sigin.xml both in layout-land and layout-portrait

Comment: so delete the onConfigurationChanged() code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your portrait xml folder layout or layout-portrait? If its layout-portrait, please dont declare it like this. Just create default 'layout' folder, the os will fetch the xml when orientation is portrait.

Next, comment the above code in java, and declare in androidmanifest.xml, android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" infront of your activity declaration and test if it works.

Comment: i am developing these for tablet i have created two layout-large-land

Comment: dude then for tablet you should have layout-large(portait) and layout-large-land for landscape. Make the correction. or Try layout-xlarge(portriat) & layout-xlarge-land(landscape)

Comment: thanks a lot its working fine now.... but i want to know how could i save my listviewdata .

Comment: Had a similar issue, the fix was actually to remove "screenSize" from the android:configChanges in my manifest.

For some reason this was applied by default when I created my activities:
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"

changing it to:
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"

Solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

why exactly are you overriding onconfigchanges? This might be what messes up your layout. android is able to handle the layout changes when you have a layout and  layout-land folder containing your layouts.

Comment: so you say need to remove onconfig changes, still it is not loading the screen when orientation changed.. its loading the same screen in landscape mode

Comment: what if you remove -portrait ? just leave a layout and layout-land folder?somewhere something went wrong... android is supposed to handle this automatically

Comment: thanks a lot its working fine now.... but i want to know how could i save my listviewdata .

Comment: i recommend storing your data in a service and call a method to fill your table in your onStart() method.